# Rotate arc in java

Tags: java, rotation, automatic-ref-counting

Hi guys i have an arc such as this one

```
g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(200, 200,100,200,90.123, 135.3456,Arc2D.OPEN));
```

now i need to rotate this arc with the use of AffineTransform  class of the java.awt.geom package so ill have to put

```
public  void AffineTransform(AffineTransform Tx){
 AffineTransform rtt = new AffineTransform();
      rtt.rotate(Math.toRadians(62));

 }
```

so i created an object and i told this object to rotate by 62 degrees which i want them to be in radians so i transform. What shall i do next to make my Arc rotate with these rad. I am really a newbie so extensive explanation will be preferred....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well instead, the `Graphics2D` class itself has rotate function, (*simpler and shorter*):

1. `rotate(double theta)`: Concatenates the current `Graphics2D` Transform with a rotation transform. Subsequent rendering is rotated by the specified radians relative to the previous origin.
2. `rotate(double theta, double x, double y)`: Concatenates the current Graphics2D Transform with a translated rotation transform. This operation is  equivalent to the following sequence of calls:

   ```
   translate(x, y);
   rotate(theta);
   translate(-x, -y);
   ```

However, after rotation as I would like to restore the Graphics state: Try creating a graphics object and disposing it off after drawing finishes:

```
   Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
   g2d.rotate(theta);
   g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(200, 200,100,200,90.123, 135.3456,Arc2D.OPEN));
   g2d.dispose();
```

Or if don't like creating and disposing:

```
   g2d.rotate(theta);
   g2d.draw(new Arc2D.Double(200, 200,100,200,90.123, 135.3456,Arc2D.OPEN));
   g2d.rotate(-theta);
```

Comment: Thank you soo much cause with affineTransform things were difficult. ok 2 questions why do i have to dispose every time drawing finishes. And secondly what if i have to draw 5 arcs or 10 arcs and i need them to rotate seperately how can i define which arc to rotate by that angle and the other by another.

Comment: this is not that you will need to dispose the graphics object every time. But after you invoke `roate(theta)` function, any subsequent drawing with the graphics object will be rotated. So, dispose when you don't want to have your drawing any more rotation. It is just a safer approach